# Node.js: How to pass environment variables with a shell command?

Tags: node.js, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to generate specific values in a Node.js script and then pass them as environment variables to a shell command, but I can't seem to get it working. What's the right way to execute a string as a shell command from Node.js while passing in my own environment variables?

The following doesn't seem to be working as I would expect:

```js
const shell = require("shelljs");
const { findPort } = require("./find-port");

async function main() {
  // imagine that `findPort(value)` starts at the provided `value` and
  // increments it until it finds an available port
  const PORT = await findPort(8000); // 8000, 8001, etc
  const DB_PORT = await findPort(3306); // 3306, 3307, etc

  shell.exec(`yarn run dev`, {
    env: {
      PORT,
      DB_PORT,
    },
    async: true,
  });
}

main();
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

Important: I don't want any values to leak out of this specific script, which is why I'm trying to avoid the `export FOO=bar` syntax, but I may be misunderstanding how that works.

I'd prefer a solution that uses `shelljs`, but I'm open to other solutions that use `child_process.exec`, `execa`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script does exactly what you ask for: it runs `yarn run dev` with your environment variables. Unfortunately, that means that it does *not* run with the system's environment variables that `yarn` depends on, like `PATH`.

You can instead run it with *both* your variables and the system's variables:

```
  shell.exec(`yarn run dev`, {
    env: {
      ...process.env,
      PORT,
      DB_PORT,
    }
  });
```

Comment: Wow! THAT was my problem? ‍♀️ Works perfectly after this fix. Thank you 